# why is Magento 2 semantic versioning at 100?

Tags: magento2, composer, version, semantic-versioning

I am using Composer to install Magento 2 and I've noticed that all packages are starting with 100. According to semantic versioning rules, Magento 2 packages should be at version 2.x.x something.

Right?

```
Package operations: 257 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals", 
    - Installing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.12): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.4.13): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.4.13): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.4.13): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing zendframework/zend-uri (2.4.13): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing zendframework/zend-loader (2.4.13): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing zendframework/zend-http (2.4.13): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing symfony/process (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/framework (100.1.8): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/framework-foreign-key (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/framework-message-queue (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing justinrainbow/json-schema (1.6.1): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-media-storage (100.1.2): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-config (100.1.5): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-backend (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-require-js (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-translation (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-theme (100.1.6): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-directory (100.1.4): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-store (100.1.6): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-ui (100.1.6): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-user (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-email (100.1.4): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-variable (100.1.2): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-authorization (100.1.2): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-eav (100.1.6): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-catalog (101.0.8): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-quote (100.1.5): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-catalog-inventory (100.1.6): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-page-cache (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-url-rewrite (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-cms-url-rewrite (100.1.2): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-cms (101.0.6): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite (100.1.4): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-import-export (100.1.4): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-security (100.1.3): Downloading (100%)", 
    - Installing magento/module-customer (100.1.7): Downloading (100%)",
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just a convention.
All modules started at `100.0.0` when Magento 2.0 was officially released.
Each module will have it's own version that has very little to do with the magento 2 version.
This was chosen so it won't be confused with the magento version.
You can get more details about the module versioning from [Alan Kent's (M2 architect) blog](https://alankent.me/?s=semantic&submit=Search)

Comment: Thanks for the link. From that source I understand that M2 is actually not respecting the rules of semantic versioning. Thanks Magento! We will see more surprises introduced by patches (as I already did).

Comment: @ElzoValugi Why do you say "not respecting the rules of semantic versioning"? They're actually pretty careful about it, although the metapackage and marketing version numbers muddy things up a bit.

Comment: @RyanHoerr is the auther saying it. Adding new functionality in a patch release is not compliant with the rules of semver. For me is unsafe then to assume that I can use version 2.1.* without breaking backwards compatibility. It already happen to me to have a break when upgrading from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8, which in theory should not introduce any changes in functionality. And is misleading using the semver lookalike versioning and then not respecting the rules.Like most developers I assumed that they did.  https://alankent.me/2016/09/20/semantic-versioning-and-patch-2-1-2/

Comment: As Alan says, module versions (100.1.7) *do* follow semver. Product/marketing version (2.1.8) does not. He even explains why. It's unfortunate, but not uncommon for software projects. Just something to get used to.